# Instrumentation Amp problems

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier

I have a 1000 times gain circuit using an INA826:

[image: Gain circuit]

Up to 2mV input 2V out, it works fine, after that point in only gets up to 2.7V.

R? is a 6.2kΩ, that brings the 49.9 r to 49.5.

Comment: What are you supplying it with?

Comment: Hi, welcome to EEsx. Your question is a fine one, just please, please try to draw a better schematic because yours is a mess. signal is going from right to left, and these cross are not supposed to be there at all. Ground is all around the place and that's a schematic, the INA would have looked way batter if represented as an inamp instead of a nice rectangle. My question finally is: what are your supply voltages?

Comment: What's the power supply voltage?  And what's the load on the circuit?

Comment: An INA826 is an instrumentation amp, not an op amp.  Two very different things.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you don't disclose your power supply voltage, but I can guess what is going on. Refer to the figures in the [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina826.pdf) as this one:

[image]

Your Vref is 0V, Vs = ??V, single supply, and your G = 1000, but you can see that the output voltage cannot safely exceed about 1.4V. That limit is the same with Vs = 5V, so it doesn't matter that much what your supply voltage is.

Now, if you give it a minus supply, such as +/-5V, things really look a lot better:

[image]

The reason for this is that internal nodes inside the chip cannot be allowed to saturate, so even though the inputs and outputs appear to be within range, the instrumentation amplifier won't function properly unless it has enough internal headroom.

It's unlikely they'll put information that's irrelevant to you in the datasheet (sometimes they do leave things out that you might find important or might not be a 'widely known' as they assume)- it's vital to make sure you understand everything in there.

Comment: Nice,  Just so @user50257 understands.  Your common mode voltage can be thought of as the average voltage of both your inputs.  Vcm = (V+in + V-in)/2 in your case that's just about zero.  (or at least that's what Spehro is assuming.)